# If statements not outputting in SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to output a texture that I've created called "die1" based on a certain keyboard input (spacebar), here is some code I have written:

```
else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Num2)) //Previous menu screen that just provides an option to roll
    {
        window.clear();
        window.draw(square);
        window.draw(text8); // text 8 says "Press space to roll die", (for now just testing on die value 1)
        window.display();
        cin.get();
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Space)) 
        {
            window.clear();
            window.draw(square);
            window.draw(die1); // die1 is just a texture of a value "1" side on a die
            window.display();
            cin.get();
        }
```

SFML is outputting value text8 in the first if statement, but nothing is happening when keyboard input(space), is applied for the second statement. I really appreciate any help, as I am fairly new to programming and using graphics in SFML. Thank you!

Comment: Try debugging the code, is it accessing the if statement?

Comment: I did debug it, that seems to be my issue. Im not sure where to place the if statement so that the compiler reads it properly.

Comment: `sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed` is supposed to be used in an event loop. It only updates when you poll for events. Start with the example under [Bringing the window to life](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-window.php) and add from there.

Comment: Why are you using cin.get?

Comment: @super sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed is a test to check the real-time state of a key and should not be used within the event loop.

Comment: Why are you clearing, displaying and drawing that square based on those conditions? It seems like you should be doing those things outside of the if block e.g. window.clear(); window.draw(square); if (sf::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Num2)) { window.draw(text8); } window.display();